# Log4net changing the log path to installation folder after logging for few seconds. Why is that?

Tags: c#, log4net

I am using log4net for to create logs of my app. One of my client reported that from few days on logs are not writing to log text file. When I go thorough the issue I found that Logs are logged to given location for few seconds and then log path automatically changing to installation folder and then continue.

My config is like this

```
 <appender name="MessageRollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="Logs\log.txt" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <encoding value="utf-8" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />
      <maximumFileSize value="5MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%message%newline%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
```

Predefined log path is set to

```
C:\Users\testuser\AppData\Roaming
```

If I change the log.txt path to the Downloads folder. There will be no issue.
I checked. There are no permission issues. Like I said logs happen to write for few seconds.

There were no errors in the app. This is c# standalong app. Why this path chaning happen?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the root tag of logger is pointed to your appender name,

```
 <root>
      <level value="ALL"/> 
      <appender-ref ref="MessageRollingFileAppender"/>
 </root>
```

Also, Make sure you check the size of the file that is getting generated, if more logs are written *(happens when application starts throwing error and you are logging all exception details)* then that could be problem to handle there may be by limiting the log `level` to only needed `error` messages.

As a second check, examine if you have configured your logger `path` to correct `log4net` config file.